# iOS Why is requestEndDate earlier than requestStartDate?

Tags: ios, urlsession

show code

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    task: URLSessionTask,
                    didFinishCollecting metrics: URLSessionTaskMetrics) {
        
        guard metrics.transactionMetrics.count > 0 else { return }
        for metric in metrics.transactionMetrics where metric.resourceFetchType == .networkLoad {
            
            if let requestStartDate = metric.requestStartDate, let requestEndDate = metric.requestEndDate {
                let requestDuration: Double = ceil(requestEndDate.timeIntervalSince(requestStartDate)*1000)
                print("requestStartDate:\(requestStartDate.timeIntervalSince1970)")
                print("requestEndDate:\(requestEndDate.timeIntervalSince1970)")
            }
            
        }
    }
```

output:

> requestStartDate:1576467073.038733
>
> requestEndDate:1576467071.590589

My question is why is requestEndDate earlier than requestStartDate?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, try testing at OC demo 
It's work for me

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didFinishCollectingMetrics:(NSURLSessionTaskMetrics *)metrics {

    self.dataModel = [NetworkMonitorDataModel new];

       if (@available(iOS 10.0, *) && [metrics.transactionMetrics count] > 0) {
        [metrics.transactionMetrics enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSURLSessionTaskTransactionMetrics *_Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *_Nonnull stop) {
            if (obj.resourceFetchType == NSURLSessionTaskMetricsResourceFetchTypeNetworkLoad) {

                NSLog(@"requestStartDate:%f",[obj.requestStartDate timeIntervalSince1970]);
                NSLog(@"requestEndDate:%f",[obj.requestEndDate timeIntervalSince1970]);

            }
        }];
    }
}
```

output:

> 2019-12-16 15:03:02.033340+0800 URLSessionInterceptpr[7024:7144654]
>   requestStartDate:1576479781.124365
>
> 2019-12-16 15:03:02.033466+0800 URLSessionInterceptpr[7024:7144654]
>   requestEndDate:1576479781.124504

But I still understand why it doesn't work on swift.